# Prove group theory equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that G is a group with precisely three distinct elements e (the
identity), a and b.

(a) Prove that ab = e.

(b) Prove that $a^2$ is neither e nor a, and hence $a^2 = b.$

(c) Deduce that $G = \{e; a; a^2\}$, and hence that G is isomorphic to
 $(\Bbb{Z}/3, +).$

Thanks to assistance from below, I have figured parts a, b and deduced $G = \{e; a; a^2\}$, but am stuck in interpreting the last portion of part c.

Comment: HINT: Use Lagrange's theorem to show that $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that groups are closed on their products. That means that $ab$ is one of those three elements $\{e,a,b\}$. Now, if $ab=a$ or $ab=b$, we have a problem. Can you figure out why? Thus, the only other option is that $ab=e$.

**Update, based on your updated question:**

Now you know that $G=\{e,a,a^2\}$. You also know that $\Bbb{Z}/3=\{0,1,2\}$ Notice that

$ee=e$ and $0+0=0$

$aa=a^2$ and $1+1=2$

$(a^2)(a^2)=a^4=a^3a=a$ and $2+2\equiv1$.

So a good guess would be that $e\mapsto 0,a\mapsto1,a^2\mapsto2$. Can you use these hints to show that this function is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb{Z}/3$? Is it a bijection?

An easier way (if you've studied cyclic groups) is to recognize that every finite group of prime order $p$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What could $ab$ be equal to? Can you rule out $ab=a$ and $ab=b$?